# Differentiate Azure Web Role SSL Certificate Thumbprint

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-roles

I have a Cloud Service with a Web Role that uses https with a corresponding SSL Certificate. (see image below).
[image]
When I publish to Azure I have to manually change the thumbprint of the SSL certificate since we have one certificate for localhost and one for 'Cloud'.
I could not find a way to configure this automatically like the other Web Role settings, where you have can set values based on 'Local' or 'Cloud' or whatever. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple! Just click on the dropdown next to `Service Configuration` and select `Cloud` from there :). Then whatever values you will specify will be applied to your cloud configuration only.

[image]

Other thing you could do is open `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` file and specify the correct thumbprint under `Certificate` node.

```
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="SSL" thumbprint="your-production-certificate-thumbprint" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
</Certificates>
```

Comment: Oh boy, I can't believe I missed such an easy thing. Thank you.

Comment: I have certificate and i dont know how to get thumbprint any help ?

Comment: @vimalprakash Just install the certificate in your certificate store and view its properties. You will find thumbprint there.